# Why is my Registration and Login code clashing PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, authentication, registration

So I have a problem with my registration and login php code. I have put them together in one php file called index.php and the registration works fine but when i try to login it clashes with the registration statements.

```
<?php
include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
// If user is already logged in, header that weenis away
if($user_ok == true){
    header("location: user.php?u=".$_SESSION["username"]);
    exit();
}
?>

<!-- .registerphp -->
<?php
// Ajax calls this NAME CHECK code to execute
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16) {
        echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">3 - 16 characters please</strong>';
        exit();
    }
    if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
        echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">Usernames must begin with a letter</strong>';
        exit();
    }
    if ($uname_check < 1) {
        echo '<strong style="color:#009900;">' . $username . ' is OK</strong>';
        exit();
    } else {
        echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
<?php
// Ajax calls this REGISTRATION code to execute
if(isset($_POST["u"])){
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
    $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $p = $_POST['p'];
    $g = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['g']);
    $c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
    // GET USER IP ADDRESS
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    // DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR USERNAME AND EMAIL
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $u_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // -------------------------------------------
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$e' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $e_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($u == "" || $e == "" || $p == "" || $g == "" || $c == ""){
        echo "The form submission is missing values.";
        exit();
    } else if ($u_check > 0){ 
        echo "The username you entered is alreay taken";
        exit();
    } else if ($e_check > 0){ 
        echo "That email address is already in use in the system";
        exit();
    } else if (strlen($u) < 3 || strlen($u) > 16) {
        echo "Username must be between 3 and 16 characters";
        exit(); 
    } else if (is_numeric($u[0])) {
        echo 'Username cannot begin with a number';
        exit();
    } else {
    // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
        // Begin Insertion of data into the database
        // Hash the password and apply your own mysterious unique salt
        include_once ("php_includes/blowfish.php");
        $cryptpass = crypt($p);
        $p_hash = cryptPass($cryptpass)."$cryptpass".cryptPass($cryptpass);
        // Add user info into the database table for the main site table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, gender, country, ip, signup, lastlogin, notescheck)       
                VALUES('$u','$e','$p_hash','$g','$c','$ip',now(),now(),now())";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
        $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
        // Establish their row in the useroptions table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO useroptions (id, username, background) VALUES ('$uid','$u','original')";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        // Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)
        if (!file_exists("user/$u")) {
            mkdir("user/$u", 0755);
        }
        // Email the user their activation link
        $to = "$e";                          
        $from = "auto_responder@pfolio.bugs3.com";
        $subject = 'PFolio Account Activation';
        $message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>PFolio Message</title></head><body style="margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;"><div style="padding:10px; background:#333; font-size:24px; color:#CCC;"><a href="http://www.pfolio.bugs3.com"><img src="http://www.pfolio.bugs3.com/images/smalllogo.png" width="215" height="50" alt="PFolio" style="border:none; float:left;"></a>PFolio Account Activation</div><div style="padding:24px; font-size:17px;">Hello '.$u.',<br /><br />Click the link below to activate your account when ready:<br /><br /><a href="http://www.pfolio.bugs3.com/activation.php?id='.$uid.'&u='.$u.'&e='.$e.'&p='.$p_hash.'">Click here to activate your account now</a><br /><br />Login after successful activation using your:<br />* Username: <b>'.$u.'</b></div></body></html>';
        $headers = "From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "signup_success";
        exit();
    }
    exit();
}
?>
<!-- .registerphp -->

<!-- .loginphp -->
<?php
// AJAX CALLS THIS LOGIN CODE TO EXECUTE
if(isset($_POST["u"])){
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES AND SANITIZE
    $u = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['u']);
    $p = crypt($_POST['p']);
    // GET USER IP ADDRESS
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($u == "" || $p == ""){
        echo "login_failed";
        exit();
    } else {
    // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $db_id = $row[0];
        $db_username = $row[1];
        $db_pass_str = $row[2];
        if($p != $db_pass_str){
            echo "login_failed";
            exit();
        } else {
            // CREATE THEIR SESSIONS AND COOKIES
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $db_pass_str;
            setcookie("id", $db_id, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("pass", $db_pass_str, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE); 
            // UPDATE THEIR "IP" AND "LASTLOGIN" FIELDS
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET ip='$ip', lastlogin=now() WHERE username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            echo $db_username;
            exit();
        }
    }
    exit();
}
?>
<!-- .loginphp -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<title>P'Folio</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link href="css/loginstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<!-- .registerjs -->
<script>
function restrict(elem){
    var tf = _(elem);
    var rx = new RegExp;
    if(elem == "email"){
        rx = /[' "]/gi;
    } else if(elem == "username"){
        rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
    }
    tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function checkusername(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    if(u != ""){
        _("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "index.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                _("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
    }
}
function signup(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var c = _("country").value;
    var g = _("gender").value;
    var status = _("status");
    if(u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || c == "" || g == ""){
        status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else if(p1 != p2){
        status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";
    } else {
        _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "index.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success"){
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    _("signupform").innerHTML = "OK "+u+", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&g="+g);
    }
}
</script>
<!-- .registerjs -->

<!-- .loginjs -->
<script>
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function login(){
    var u = _("user_name").value;
    var p = _("pass_word").value;
    if(u == "" || p == ""){
        _("sta_tus").innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else {
        _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
        _("sta_tus").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "index.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                    _("sta_tus").innerHTML = "Login unsuccessful, please try again.";
                    _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.location = "user.php?u="+ajax.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("u="+u+"&p="+p);
    }
}
</script>
<!-- .loginjs -->
</head>

  <body>
<!-- .wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">
<!-- .header-->
  <header class="header"> <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" title="P'Folio"> </header>
  <!-- .header-->

  <!-- .login -->
  <div class="login">
    <form id="loginform" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div><img class="h1" src="images/lh.png" alt="login%20here"/></div>
      <div><img class="p1" src="images/wb.png" alt="welcome%20back"/></div>
      <input type="text" id="user_name" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16" class="loginboxes" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" id="pass_word" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="100" class="loginboxes" placeholder="Password">
      <br />
      <button id="loginbtn" onclick="login()">Log In</button>
      <p id="sta_tus"></p>
      <a href="#">Forgot Your Password?</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- .login -->

  <!-- .main -->
  <main class="content">
    <p>Are you a musician, a model, actor or actress or anyone with a talent then sign up for P'Folio.
      Here on P'Folio we look to give you space to upload a portfolio for you to be noticed. </p>
  </main>
  <!-- .main -->

  <!-- .signup -->
  <div class="signup">
    <form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div><img class="h1" src="images/caa.png" alt="create%20account"/></div>
      <div><img class="p1" src="images/ntm.png" alt="new%20to%20P'Folio"/></div>
      <span id="unamestatus"></span>
      <input id="username" type="text" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16" placeholder="Username" class="registerboxes">
      <input id="email" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88" placeholder="Email" class="registerboxes">
      <input id="pass1" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password" class="registerboxes">
      <input id="pass2" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="100" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="registerboxes">
      <select id="gender" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" class="registerboxes">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose...</option>
        <option value="m">Male</option>
        <option value="f">Female</option>
      </select>
      <select id="country" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" class="registerboxes">
        <?php include_once("template_country_list.php"); ?>
      </select>
      <div class="conditions">By clicking Sign Up, 
        you agree to our <a href="#">Terms</a> and that 
        you have read our <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> , 
        including our <a href="#">Cookie Use</a> .</div>
      <button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>
      <span id="status"></span>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- .signup -->

  <!-- .footer -->
  <footer class="footer">
    <div id="legal"><a class="legal" href="JavaScript:newPopup('Login/Legal/Terms.php');">Terms</a> | <a class="legal" href="JavaScript:newPopup('Login/Legal/Privacy.php');">Privacy</a></div>
    <div id="font"><a class="font">P'folio © 2014</a></div>
  </footer>
  <!-- .footer --> 
</div>
<!-- .wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Why is my Registration and Login code not working?

Comment: Login & Registration are checking the same condition: `isset($_POST["u"])`

Comment: @JustinIurman please can you expand

Answer (score 0):

For registration and also login don't use AJAX. It is better. You may use *classic* JavaScript for pre-checking of correct setting of username and password, but don't use AJAX for own login and registration process.

Also it is good to split both processes into different places. I have not ever seen any web where login and registration would be done from the same place - and via AJAX.

For username checking you may use order

```
preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-z0-9]{3,16}/i', $_POST['username']);
```

that checks if username does not start with number and is long at least 3 signs and not longer than 16 signs. Also it allows small letters and numbers.